# Statistical learning and differentiation in a Hilbert space

Tags: optimization, hilbert-spaces, lagrange-multiplier, machine-learning, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $\Phi\colon\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathcal{H}$ some function with $K$ being the RKHS kernel. Let $B_i>0$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots ,n$ and we are interested in solving the following $2$-norm optimization problem (classes are $1$ or $-1$)
$$\min_{w\in\mathcal{H},\ a\in\mathbb{R}}\left\{\frac12\langle w,w\rangle+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{B_i}2\left(1-y_i(\langle w,\Phi(x_i)\rangle+a)\right)^2\right\}.$$
This is a standard $2$-norm soft margin optimization problem in statistical learning theory. My question has to do with the way Lagrangian is used.

I introduce slack variables $\xi_i$, transform the initial problem into
$$\min_{h\in\mathcal{H}}\left\{\frac12\langle w,w\rangle+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{B_i}2\xi_i^2\right\},$$
with $1-\xi_i-y_i(\langle w,\Phi(x_i)\rangle+a)\leq 0, \ \ \ i=1,2,\ldots ,n.$ Lagrangian is 
$$L(w,a,\xi,\alpha)=\frac12\langle w,w\rangle +\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{B_i}2\xi_i^2+\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j(1-\xi_j-y_j(\langle w,\Phi(x_j)\rangle+a)).$$
In order to find the extrema, I want to differentiate in respect to $w$. However, in that case we are considering the lagrangian as a functional on the Hilbert space $H$ and questions arise about differentiability and even the definition of the derivative. This problem is avoided by using the representation theorem, which states that 
$$w(\cdot)=\sum_{j=1}^nc_jK(x_j,\cdot),$$
for some $c_j\in\mathbb{R}$. That way we can vary the constants $c_j$ and differentiate in respect to $c_j$-s. Can we simply not use representation theorem and differentiate in respect to $w$? Can the method of Lagrange multipliers be extended onto Hilbert spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once wondered about this myself (see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/551585/would-support-vector-machines-work-on-arbitrary-hilbert-spaces) on cross validated). Now, after a M.Sc. in Optimization, I feel I can offer a better answer.

One way to justify the derivation is indeed to use the Representation Theorem (which is more an observation than a theorem tbh) and then apply standard Optimization tools (KKT, Dual, etc.) to get the desired answer.

I would like to note, however, that you don't even need to introduce the coordinates $c_i$, as Analysis on a finite dimensional Banach space is identical to Analysis on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and so standard tools apply again (take a look at the [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative)).

If you want to understand the details, I highly recomend the note [Formulations of Support Vector Machines: A Note from an Optimization Point of View](https://doi.org/10.1162/089976601300014547).

Hope this helps!